# why should I override equals and hashcode method for following scnerio

Tags: java, hashmap, overriding, equals, hashcode

why I need to override for direct access of value in Hash map.That is if insert data into hashmap as follow HashMap,I could get value by giving the Key as Integer ,would get Object as Value.In this case is it necessary to Override equals() and hashCode() method?Please give suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to override anything to use an object as a *value* in a `HashMap`.

Only  *keys* need to have a working `hashCode()`.

However, you need to implement these two methods (technically only `equals`, but these two are a set, really) if you want to use things like `Map#containsValue`, `List#indexOf` or `Collection#contains` (and these should not just be using reference identity).

Comment: yes you correct thilo.I was tested for list#indexOf,set#contains both required override  equals() and hashCode().Even HashMap also might required override operation suppose  if HashMap key is "Object" and value is something.I am correct?if not please brief me.

Comment: Yes, *keys* of a HashMap definitely need a working hashCode() method.

Answer (score -1):

`hashCode()` is used to search for a specific elem when you want to retrieve it from a hashTable. `hashCode()` doesn't have to  be distinct. in fact, you could just return the same integer for all your instance, but then,  elems are stored in a list instead of a hashTable, and will cause a performance problem.

- By default implementation of `hashCode()` (which is the implementation of `Object` for subClass to extents from )of JVM returns a integer according to the memory address of the object, so this should be enough, but this implement was not required by the JVM standard.
- By default(Class `object`), implementation of equals() will return `true` and only return `true` when they have same reference , ie `obj1 == obj2`. [read this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

keep in mind that:

- equal objects **must** have same `hashCode()`
- those have same `hashCode()` are not required to  be equal to each other.

I think override of `hashCode()` is not needed in most situations(not extends from other Class), cause modern JVMs has done 
pretty good job for you.

So conclusion is:

if your super class have overwrite the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method, then you should override them, or at least take a look at the implementation, and decide whether you should override them.

Comment: It's 'override', not 'overwrite', and you've missed the point completely. He is asking about values, not keys.